# Launch and Pass String to Destination View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-passing

I am trying to do the seemingly simple task of passing a string to a viewcontroller with a storyboardid in code but am getting a compiler error: 'View Controller does not have member "myString"'

The destination view controller has the storyboard id:myVC  and here is my code to launch it:

```
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "secondSB", bundle: nil)
        let destvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVC")
        destvc.myString = "mapme"
```

The viewcontroller is assigned to a class that looks like this:

```
class myMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var myString:String = ""
   }
```

This seems extremely straightforward but then again I am relatively new to Swift.  If I take out the line with the error, btw, the VC does launch fine.  What could I be missing that is causing this error?

Comment: Those protocols and that outlet have nothing to do with this problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instantiateViewController` returns the base class `UIViewController`, you have to cast the type to your subclass.

Please name classes, structs and enums with starting capital letter

```
let destvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myVC") as! MyMapViewController
```